# Minecraft 1.20.4 fabric 0.15.3 mod recipe not working

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I wanted to get into Minecraft modding with fabric, so I found a tutorial on youtube ( https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKGarocXCE1EO43Dlf5JGh7Yk-kRAXUEJ&si=C76zSHazzUJUNVHX ) and coded along. When it came to the custom recipes, what i coded was not working, even though I typed it exactly like it is in the tutorial.

I tried to make custom recipes, using json files, like shown in the tutorial:

.json for recipe 1:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:crafting_shapeless",
  "category": "building",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "item": "tutorialmod:ruby_block"
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "item": "tutorialmod:ruby",
    "count": 9
  }
}
```

.json for recipe 2:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
  "category": "misc",
  "pattern": [
    "###",
    "###",
    "###"
  ],
  "key": {
    "#": {
      "item": "tutorialmod:ruby"
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "item": "tutorialmod:ruby_block"
  }
}
```

I thought I´d get a working crafting recipe in minecraft, but when i launched the game with that mod, and put in the crafting recipe, nothing happend.

Edit 1: forgot to link my github repository: https://github.com/Ludowigo/tutorialmod-template-1.20.4-NEW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datapacks and resource (asset) packs are two different things, the first loaded by the server, the second by the client.

You however put the data pack (data directory) INTO the assets pack. Move it outside.

Comment: Thank you very much, i realiesed , i am very incompetent ^^